# Visual Studio regenerating designer vb partial classes with improper parent class names

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, code-generation, windows-forms-designer

I have a base class for all my dialogs in the program im writing in Visual Basic.
I was adding a new data source from a SQLite database i had created to work out some errors i ran into, then all of a sudden( as in i dont know what i did to trigger this), Visual Studio started regenerating all of my dialogs designer Partial class definitions, with the Namespace prepended to the parent class name.
I believe its throwing an exception because its resolving as "RepackWPF.RepackWPF.DialogBase" instead of just "RepackWPF.DialogBase"...

I went through, TWICE, and manually corrected this, however, it keeps regenerating them with the improper names...
I imagine I could turn this generation tool off, however I WANT it to be used, I just want it to be correct the way it was before.
I've attacked images of the pertinent code, because I have reasons why I cannot disclose the actual major code block or file.

[image: The error im getting after i go through and manually change the files and class names]
[image: How it appears in the actual form definition code when inheriting]

[image: The Improper name]

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Am I using the wrong label here? VB.net?
Ill just refer to it as Visual Basic

Comment: Go look in your project's properties and clear the Root Namespace entry.  The root namespace is automatically added as part of the namespace.  I prefer to clear this out and explicitly set my namespaces as needed with the `Namespace` keyword.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this, and for some reason it didnt really solve the problem, When I cleared that option, it also removed the import itself, so essentially it went from "namespace.namespace.class", to "class". Once i remove the root namespace, does that mean i then have to explicitly call each class by their fully qualified name?

Also, will FREAKING VS regenerate the file and just delete my manual changes anyway? It seems to do that everywhere else

Comment: You can still use the `Namespace` keyword to explicitly set your namespaces, it just won't make the root namespace part of it anymore.  The designer file is always subject to regeneration so you should never make changes to that file that you need to keep.